# set one picturebox image on another picturebox image on location 480,380 by clicking

Tags: c#

I want set one picturebox image on another picturebox image on location 480,380 by clicking on the image.i dont know how to set and where to write the code.its like neckels will add on customer image neck  by clicking.its urgent and i will be thankful to u.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the "best" answer, but it might be the easiest if you are using the visual express IDE, and you said you were in a hurry.

1) Create a picturebox in your form (pictureBox1 or whatever it's called by default). 
2) Double click on your form to create a form load function.  It should look something like :

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }
```

3) Add code to it to create another picturebox and add it to your first picturebox:

```
    PictureBox ChildBox;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChildBox = new PictureBox();
        ChildBox.Visible = false;
        ChildBox.Location = new Point(0, 0); // change this to your coordinates, 480 by 380
        // the next 2 lines are just so that you can see the changes
        ChildBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(ChildBox);
    }
```

4) Double Click on PictureBox1 in your form to create the following stub:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    }
```

5) Change it to

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ChildBox.Visible = true;
    }
```

That will make a picture box "appear" at the coordinates that you want.

Comment: childbox error has gone.but picturebox2 click option is disable.and nothing adding on picturebox1

Comment: send me ur email adrees atleast u can check where am i doing mistak in code

Answer (score 0):

A simple example

```
private List<Tuple<Image, int, int>> images = new List<Tuple<Image, int, int>>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //load the customer image
    this.picBoxTarget.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(...);
    //load the necklaces image
        this.picBoxSource.Image = Image.FromFile(...);
    }

    private void picBoxSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.picBoxSource.Image == null)
            return;

        //when click the picBoxSource, add the image to list
        //(you may need to check whether there is another one necklace in the list, if not allowed to wear two)
        this.images.Add(Tuple.Create(this.picBoxSource.Image, 480, 380));
        //and make the picBoxTarget redraw
        this.picBoxTarget.Invalidate();
    }

    private void picBoxTarget_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var img in this.images)
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img.Item1, img.Item2, img.Item3);
    }
```

Comment: can u please help me,where i have to write the code.because m new in c#

Comment: what is that you do not understand?

Comment: system.eventargs doesnot contain a definition for graphics..error showing

Comment: I think you mean picBoxTarget_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
. Select picBoxTarget, open the Property window and switch to Events  Tab, then you can find an event named Paint, double click it. you can found this.picBoxTarget.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.picBoxTarget_Paint); in Form1.Designer.cs, so also you can write it by your self

Comment: i have done.no error is coming.but after running only two image is showing.nothing is working.nothing is adding or merging.neckles is not going to customer neck.even picboxsource button click option is disable.

Comment: i think there is a small mistake in somewhere.if u send me ur email then i will send the code.i can check where is the mistake.